# What is the origin of the foreign word サクランボ?

Tags: etymology, history, nouns

`サクランボ` means `cherry` in English.

However, it is different from the direct conversion of cherry, `チェリー`.

What is the origin of this word?

Which language does it originate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## From Japanese (and perhaps some Chinese)

There is no borrowing here, as the opening part explicitly shows Japanese **sakura**. The etymology is, as most often assumed,

```
さくらんぼ < 桜{さくら}の坊{ボウ}
```

, where 坊 ‘monk’ could refer to the cherries being as smooth as a monk’s shaven head. The word is still spelt 桜ん坊 in Kanji, so there is nothing really surprising here beyond kun plus on compound.

Comment: The OP also asked for how it is different from チェリー.

Comment: @ajsmart:  Answers do not need to resolve every part of the question (i.e., [partial answers are OK](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)).

Comment: This answers my question very well.  I was hypothesizing that the word came from another language.  The origin of this word is far more interesting than I originally thought.  ありがとうございます。

Comment: In this case, 坊 is not monk but a child or a baby.
ウリ坊　is a wild boar baby.
It has nothing to do with a monk’s shaven head.

Comment: Monk's head, baby, they're both theories...If the experts aren't sure, how come everyone is stating it like fact without citing some kind of source.　http://gogen-allguide.com/sa/sakuranbo.html　諸説あり